# Old "best book/resource" questions

Tags: discussion

While doing Citizens Patrol on the [Flagged Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) page, I noticed that quite a few older questions had been flagged as not constructive. These are *What is the best book or resource for xyz?* type questions, for example:

- [Python Wget?/Scripting books?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805683/python-wget-scripting-books)
- [What are the best books for Hibernate & JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96729/what-are-the-best-books-for-hibernate-jpa)
- [Books for Operation Systems, Protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426029/books-for-operation-systems-protocols)
- [Looking for some good books/resources on understanding Bittorrent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383862/looking-for-some-good-books-resources-on-understanding-bittorrent)

Now these types of questions are discouraged on SO, hence the amount of them that have been flagged.

While I certainly agree that we don't want new versions of these questions, are some of them still worth keeping? Some of them have a lot of answers, and some of those answers carry a number of up votes, some of those answers still carry some **value**. Some of these questions also have the potential to be considered canonical (although the ones used as examples above won't fit that category).

Now let's take the discussion one step further - what should be done with answers that are marked as the correct answer, but it is no longer correct? An example is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947/visual-studio-08-spell-check-addin/102168#102168), where the link no longer works (stale, produces a handled 404), and the company no longer lists the product? (This product or one identical appears to be now owned by [submain](http://submain.com/products/codespell.aspx)).

- should the link be "fixed", considering that it is quite possible to make a mistake and link to the wrong product?
- should the answer be edited and a note inserted as I have done?
- should the answer be flagged for deletion?
- should the accumulated links to resources/books be aggregated into one Community owned answer and all the separate answers then deleted?

(Apologies if this question is a dupe or partial dupe - I do keep a close eye on Meta but a previous discussion may have slipped my attention).

Answer (score 1):

I decided to follow up the and edit the answer as I was able to see find the note on the SubMain blog indicating the acquisition. I do believe that my edit is messy and that the correct edit should be to remove the original link. However I left it in because of this question.